# SCSS Compilation Error : TypeError: extractedChunk.addGroup is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm, sass

After updating npm modules, I tried to run "npm run compile:scss" which was working fine before, I keep getting the following error:

Node: 11.14.0
NPM: 6.7.0

```
D:\*\custom\common\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:217
            extractedChunk.addGroup(chunkGroup);
                           ^

TypeError: extractedChunk.addGroup is not a function
    at chunks.forEach (D:\*\custom\common\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:217:28)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at compilation.hooks.optimizeTree.tapAsync (D:\*\custom\common\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:209:16)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\*\custom\common\node_modules\sgmf-scripts\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\*\custom\common\node_modules\sgmf-scripts\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.seal (D:\*\custom\common\node_modules\sgmf-scripts\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1342:27)
    at compilation.finish.err (D:\*\custom\common\node_modules\sgmf-scripts\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:675:18)
    at hooks.finishModules.callAsync.err (D:\*\custom\common\node_modules\sgmf-scripts\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1261:4)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\Demandware Project\*\custom\common\node_modules\sgmf-scripts\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\*\custom\common\node_modules\sgmf-scripts\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app_common@0.0.1 compile:scss: `sgmf-scripts --compile css`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the app_common@0.0.1 compile:scss script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-26T11_26_27_193Z-debug.log
```